# GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection:

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, oracle11g

We are getting the following error at a customer site from time to time (this is not consistent) and we see it in different entities

```
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not initialize a collection: [.......]
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2000)
at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:36)
at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:565)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:60) 
    .
    .
    .
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No more data to read from socket
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:190)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:286)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1123)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1075)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:480)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:219)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:925)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1132)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:977)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1275)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3500)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3545)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:92)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1786)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:635)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:197)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:1993)
... 128 more
```

In the oracle alert log we see **ORA-03137**: TTC protocol internal error

Upgrading \ patching the Oracle or JDBC driver is not an option.
Did anyone run into these issues?

Comment: Why is upgrading Oracle or the JDBC driver not an option?

Comment: This is customer site - we own the java code not the Oracle instance.

Comment: Which JDBC driver version is in use (which btw is part of your application and you should be able to upgrade if it is old)

Comment: We are using oracle driver version 10.2.0.4.0. We tried to upgrade it a while ago and had some major performance issues. This is the reason this is not an option though it is part of my application.